# DataTables - server-side processing in Python/Flask - Not working connection to server-side script

Tags: python, flask, datatables

I'm struggling with this for several days. I'm trying to implement Sergio Llanna's server-side solution to my existing project.

[Sergio's DataTables server-side processing](https://github.com/SergioLlana/datatables-flask-serverside)

and this is my implementation:

[My DataTables server-side processing](https://github.com/culterone/clt)

The difference is, that my solution grabs the data from MySQL database instead of local file. I think that I'm pretty close to make it work, data from database are displayed in the table correctly. **When I turn off serverSide option, sorting and searching is working fine, but when I turn it on, everytime I click on the column, search or anything else I get just "Processing..."** Flask debug mode is on. There is no error in the browser's development tools or flask development server.

My JSON XHR (response):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "cola": "Hello", 
      "colb": "How is it going", 
      "colc": 1, 
      "cold": 4
    }, 
    {
      "cola": "Sample text", 
      "colb": "Another sample", 
      "colc": 2, 
      "cold": 9
    }, 
    {
      "cola": "Kurnik hosi", 
      "colb": "Guten tag", 
      "colc": 3, 
      "cold": 3
    }, 
    {
      "cola": "Achiles", 
      "colb": "Patus", 
      "colc": 4, 
      "cold": 1
    }, 
    {
      "cola": "Kim", 
      "colb": "Kiduk", 
      "colc": 5, 
      "cold": 8
    }, 
    {
      "cola": "Pastina", 
      "colb": "Zavada", 
      "colc": 6, 
      "cold": 9
    }, 
    {
      "cola": "Dolna", 
      "colb": "Marikova", 
      "colc": 7, 
      "cold": 9
    }
  ], 
  "draw": 1, 
  "recordsFiltered": 10, 
  "recordsTotal": 7
}
```

I think the problem is with the request sent from browser, but this is my first Python/Flask project, so I'm not sure.
Thank you for any advice.

Used technologies:
OS Debian 9,
DB MariaDB 10,
Flask-SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit unclear to me what you exactly changed compared to the original files, so I went ahead and tried adding SQLAlchemy support to Sergio's original project.

`__init__.py` changes:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(flask_app)

from app.mod_tables.models import TableBuilder, SomeTable, add_some_random_db_entries
db.create_all()
add_some_random_db_entries()
table_builder = TableBuilder()
```

`models.py` changes:

```
from app.mod_tables.serverside.serverside_table import ServerSideTable
from app.mod_tables.serverside import table_schemas
from app import db

DATA_SAMPLE = [
    {'A': 'Hello!', 'B': 'How is it going?', 'C': 3, 'D': 4},
    {'A': 'These are sample texts', 'B': 0, 'C': 5, 'D': 6},
    {'A': 'Mmmm', 'B': 'I do not know what to say', 'C': 7, 'D': 16},
    {'A': 'Is it enough?', 'B': 'Okay', 'C': 8, 'D': 9},
    {'A': 'Just one more', 'B': '...', 'C': 10, 'D': 11},
    {'A': 'Thanks!', 'B': 'Goodbye.', 'C': 12, 'D': 13}
]

class SomeTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    cola = db.Column('A', db.String(2))
    colb = db.Column('B', db.String(2))
    colc = db.Column('C', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cold = db.Column('D', db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, cola, colb, colc, cold):
        self.cola = cola
        self.colb = colb
        self.colc = colc
        self.cold = cold

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
             'A': self.cola,
             'B': self.colb,
             'C': self.colc,
             'D': self.cold
        }


def add_some_random_db_entries():
    letters = 'arstarstarstarstaars'
    for i in range(10):
        item = SomeTable(letters[i], letters[i + 1: i + 3], i, i + 1)
        db.session.add(item)
    db.session.commit()


def make_data_sample_from_db():
    newlist = []
    for row in SomeTable.query.all():
        newlist.append(row.serialize)
    return newlist


class TableBuilder(object):

    def collect_data_clientside(self):
        return {'data': DATA_SAMPLE}

    def collect_data_serverside(self, request):
        columns = table_schemas.SERVERSIDE_TABLE_COLUMNS
        data = make_data_sample_from_db()
        return ServerSideTable(request, data, columns).output_result()
```

You should be able to just add the database URL, and it should work the same from there.

However, this method of getting filtered results is quite inefficient, especially with large databases. It is only good for small databases, because you have to query the entire table, and the filter it using dictionaries.

I would probably check out `flask-admin`. It has a lot of the filtering build into the package itself, using SQLAlchemy's filtering support, which means that it is a lot quicker than this approach.

Here's the modified repo on [github](https://github.com/joost823/datatables-flask-serverside).

Comment: Joost, thank you. I try to implement server-side solution to make it faster. Much faster than it is with the for loop to write data to the table. I used the for loop for several hundreds of rows without server-side processing mode. Now I have 30k rows and it takes 40 seconds to create table and it's useless. In the near future, there will be about 150k rows. Server-side processing is used for displaying large tables on the web (millions of rows), therefore I need to implement this. Unfortunately, DataTables has no flask/python server-side script available. Only PHP :(

Comment: It won't be much faster because of the way Sergio implemented it. Getting all the data, and then filtering it is just not efficient (that's why you have SQL). I would really suggest looking into flask admin. It's extremely powerful and has a lot of features datatables also has (I've used both extensively). Check out [some of the examples](http://examples.flask-admin.org/sqla/simple/admin/post/?sort=0&desc=1).

Comment: Thanks. I expected, that there is only one way how to implement DataTables server-side processing and everytime it makes new query for every view, which is fast. I just watch some youtube video about flask-admin, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Please, can you consider if flask-admin is suitable to my needs? I need to display data from mysql table with 150k rows. I need to sort the columns and add my filters (many checkboxes). Then I need to export the filtered data to various formats (DataTables has this functionality). When I will click on filtered row, I need to roll out "submenu" with another info from database (info from other tables). Could you please tell me which parts of my needs are achievable with flask-admin and if it's reasonable to switch from DataTables? I dedicated about 2 months to DataTables :(

Comment: Hmm, that's a very specific problem. I would probably stick with datatables in that case. I would however, NOT use the sergio's answer. Just let the user set all filters at once, then save the filters the user set, and then use `SomeTable.query.filter_by(col1=user_inputted_filter, col2=user_inputted_filter2).all()` or something of the like to get the relevant results.

Comment: Thank you, Joost. I switched from python to php. Now the basic functionality is working and I think there will be much more examples in php than python.